# trying to show single post but displays all post on a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, single

Good day,

I was trying to show a specific post when a user click on the title but all other post are shown as well, how can I filter it?

for example when I click link http://levelup.sic.edu.ph/archives/students/post-no-2
the other post are shown as well.

or How do I get the title from the link so I could use it as my parameter on my query?

here's my single-students.php

```
<?php
/**
* The Template for displaying all single posts.
*
* @package Motif
*/

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php query_posts( 'post_type=students'); ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query_posts( 'post_type=students');` that changes the main query to be for all posts with the type `students`. It's showing all the posts because you're asking it to.

If this is on a single post page, your loop will be sufficient, no need for extra `query_posts` calls or anything like that. Just remove that bit from your code.

In fact, you [probably shouldn't use `query_posts` at all](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012).

Comment: lol. that was a stupid mistake of mine sir.. thank you for correcting that :) really helped me. Thank you sir.